# Проверка email на совпадение используя через ajax

Tags: php, ajax

Нужно проверить email в базе на совпадение. Отправляю email через ajax. Думаю: напишу `echo 'false'`на сервере если email есть такой и потом в  `success`передам значение переменной `if(data == 'false'){var ch = true}`. Но эта переменная видна только внутри  `success` =(. Как мне выкрутиться ? или как это вообще правильно делается ? Не делал еще через ajax проверок на email.

```js
$.ajax({
            url: '/page/email',
            method: 'POST',
            data: {
                email: email
            },
            success:function (data) {
                
                }
            },
            error: function (err) {
                console.log('Error',err);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Хм.. вам просто нужно сменить значение некой переменной ch объявленной вне области видимости success? Ну так.. объявляете эту ch где-то вверху, над всем этим, и меняете когда нужно. Или я чего-то не понял?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$.ajax({
  url: '/page/email',
  type: 'POST',
  data: {
    email: email
  }
}).done(function(res) { // success устарела, её не стоит использовать
  if (res == 'true') {
    consol.elog('Well done!');
  } else if (res == 'false') {
    consol.elog('Email not found');
  } else {
    alert('Произошла ошибка выполнения запроса');
    console.log(res);
  }
}).fail(function(res) {
  alert('Произошла ошибка выполнения запроса');
  console.log(res);
});
```

```html
// php код
if (_email_найден) {
  echo true;
} esle {
  echo false;
}
```